# How to prevent cross site scripting in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

How to prevent cross site scripting in classic asp?

I want to prevent client side input like html tag and any scripting tag in classic asp textbox.

I was trying using method Server.HTMLEncode "Name= Server.HTMLEncode(Request.Form("txtName"))"
but still data is inserted in Database Like "<h1>Raj</h1>"
and also this data is retrieved in textbox as it is but I want to remove tags when inserting and retrieved also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to remove HTML completely:

```vb
Function Remove_HTML(ByVal str)

    Dim RegEx : Set RegEx = New RegExp
    
        RegEx.Pattern = "<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*>"
        RegEx.Global = True
        RegEx.Multiline = True
        RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
        Remove_HTML = RegEx.Replace(str,"")
        
    Set RegEx = Nothing
    
End Function
```

You say that `Server.HTMLEncode` isn't encoding angle brackets? That doesn't make any sense. You'll need to post your code.

When inserting, updating or selecting user submitted data from a database, you should always check and sanitize the data before including it in any database command.

If you're returning the users raw input, for example on a search page (**x** result(s) found for **search_term**), you should always use `Server.HTMLEncode` before returning, and don't forget to use it if you're populating a search box input or text area too.